# PyCharm keeps throwing "Memory Error" even after heap size increase/reset

Tags: python, pycharm, out-of-memory

So I have this script, using pandas dataframe mostly to deal with my data. The script works when I process about 10 days worth of data; but if I do 11 days worth of data, it'll start complaining "**MemoryError**".

I've read through almost all the posts I think are relevant. Sample ones that I feel like are most related:

1. [PyCharm Running Out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137671/pycharm-running-out-of-memory)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/919204/how-can-i-increase-the-memory-heap-in-pycharm/1141412#1141412?newreg=8c1cf6510b64441a987d6ef0e0cab23d
3. http://web.archive.org/web/20160503095110/http://www.avricot.com/blog/?post/2010/05/03/Get-started-with-java-JVM-memory-(heap,-stack,-xss-xms-xmx-xmn...)

I've changed my max heap size to 1024 (according to above posts, 1024 is the maximum?)
and I've also increased the min to 256 (it was 1/2 of that originally).

Specs about my laptop:

- 32GB RAM.
- CPU = 2 cores
- max speed = 2.81GHz
- Logical processors = 4

When I run the program/script, I do not see spike in memory consumption; it's pretty steady... so I'm now confused. 
But I do see a lot spikes in CPU consumption. Could that be a problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *pycharm* isn't throwing anything. I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with PyCharm. the `MemoryError` is being throw by your program, likely because you are out of memory. You'll have to provide way more details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what other details do i have to provide? i'll provide all the necessary info!

Comment: Well for starters, more details about your program...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry for my late response! i'm still looking into this and trying to figure out maybe it's my program issue. thanks very much for the advice and really appreciate your help every time!