# Pycharm installation problem on Kali Linux ( java lang out of memory )

Tags: python, pycharm, virtual-machine, kali-linux

First of all, I am sorry if what I will describe isn't clear, I'm learning english and I'm new in this website and new in the field of IT.

So, I tried to install PyCharm on my VirtualBox (Kali Linux), but when I launch the pycharm.sh file, there is this error. The problem is that I tried to modify the Xmx and Xms parameters, but I tried everything (Xmx:512, Xms:128, Xmx:1028m, Xms:512, etc.) but I always have this error. My machine has 5GB of RAM and 11GB of disk storage. It worked ONE time without this error; it was with Xmx:512m and Xms:128m, but I turned off the machine and the error reappeared. Can you please find a solution?

Comment: May I ask why do you need to install PyCharm on Kali? This OS is highly specialized, I can't imagine a use of such complicated IDE there - it's capabilities will be likely useless for scripting and automation or quick prototyping.

Comment: I found on udemy a specific formation about cybersecurity ( his final project was to create a vulnerability detector ). This formation suggested me to do so, and all of the websites about ethical hacking advice adviced me to learn how to use Linux. I already master python so I thought trying to master Kali was a good idea

Comment: Yeah, Kali is a good idea, PyCharm is probably less of:) I mean, you don't need pycharm to write and run python code - vim or some simple gui editor should work better for understanding and quick scripting. You likely don't need most of the fancy ide features.

Comment: I didn't think about that. I will try to install vs code on my virtual machine then, hope that will work. You seem mastering this domain, so have you some advices about this ? And thank you for all your answers !

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48954908

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you're encountering a Java heap space error when launching PyCharm.
Try this: open the `pycharm.vmoptions` file in the PyCharm installation directory and set both Xmx and Xms values to the same value, for example, Xmx=512m and Xms=512m.
Save the file and try launching PyCharm again. If the issue persists, you may want to check if there are other conflicting configurations or consider reinstalling PyCharm.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Guys please answer, I really need this. And Raju, what you suggested me doesn't work